# bootstrap datapicker component using simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, simple-form

I am struggling to add a `f.input` simple form line of code to add a bootstrap datepicker with component.

Following the datepicker examples I can add the bootstrap datepicker with component using the following code:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2013" readonly>
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
  })
</script
```

how can I rewrite the above div as a `f.input` simple_form line of code

Answer (score 0):

> application.js or any .js file

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
 });
```

view file

```
<div class="input-append date">
   <%=f.text_field :field_name, :class=>'datepicker'%>
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, the code i am using is working but i was looking at how i can rewrite is as a simple form f.input command

Answer (score 0):

For my project, i used this : https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.

It's a good gem and easy to use

In my project, i create a **date_time_input.rb** file in **app/inputs/date_time.input.rb** for override simple form date time input.

```
class DateTimeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::DateTimeInput
  def input
    #template.content_tag(:div, super)
    "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Into the view :

```
= f.input :date, :required => true, :input_html => { “data-behaviour” => “datepicker” }
```

And JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on(“focus”, “[data-behaviour~=’datepicker’]”, function(e){
    $(this).datepicker({“format”: “dd/mm/yyyy”, “weekStart”: 1, “autoclose”: true});
    });
});
```

This is my article for do that in french :-D

http://blog.jumboweb.fr/post/42841191962/datepicker-bootstrap-simple-form-avec-rails

Comment: Hi I am using this gem as well, what i am trying to do is rewrite my div as a simple form f.input line of code